# sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode() vs java.net.URLDecoder.decode()

Tags: java, urldecode

I have some legacy code that is calling `sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode()`. I would like to avoid calling vendor specific functions, so I want to replace the call with something else.

Can I use java.net.URLDecoder.decode() as a drop-in replacement or is there something I should look out for?

The call is used to convert a file URL to a normal path inside a custom classloader:

```
URL url = //...
if(url.getProtocol().equals("file"))) {
    String path = url.getFile().replace('/', File.separatorChar);
    path = ParseUtil.decode(path);
    if (path.endsWith(File.separator)){
       path += "-";
    }
    p = new FilePermission(path, SecurityConstants.FILE_READ_ACTION);
 }
```

(Note that this is almost exactly the same code as in [`java.net.UrlClassLoader.getPermissions()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.java.html#661))

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say since the semantics of `ParseUtil` are not well documented.

I think would ditch the code entirely and replace it with code that uses `URI` and the `File(URI)` constructor.

Comment: Absolutely! Even if it *isn't* the same, the sun impl could change tomorrow! Yikes! Change it!

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url = //...
if(url.getProtocol().equals("file"))) {
    String path = url.getFile().replace('/', File.separatorChar);
    path = ParseUtil.decode(path);
    if (path.endsWith(File.separator)){
       path += "-";
    }
    p = new FilePermission(path, SecurityConstants.FILE_READ_ACTION);
 }
```

I doubt that this code is doing anything useful at all. Certainly any code that does that replace() operation is immediately suspect. Try new File(url.toURI()).getPath() or .getAbsolutePath().

The next question is what does it think it is doing constructing a Permission? That doesn't get you anywhere either. The Security Manager will do that itself when necessary and check the resulting permission and throw a SecurityException if necessary. Constructing a Permission yourself doesn't give you that permission.

Comment: The code is in the getPermissions()-method of a custom classloader. I believe these are the permissions that end up being passed to the Security Manager, so I guess it serves a purpose. Also, I can see that it is almost a cut'n'paste from Sun's UrlClassLoader (see update to my question) and I guess (hope?) that Sun know what they are doing.

Comment: @Rasmus Faber OK. Re cut/paste, Sun knew what they were doing in the JDK that code was copy/pased from that called ParseUtil.decode() in the version that existed at that time. Very likely it hasn't changed at all ... but nevertheless external code should not rely on it. Try some variant of the URI code I posted.